# Join multiple tables with few condition and without relationship

Tags: sql, join, search

This has been self-answered below with:

> Im so sorry guys, there is nothing wrong in my query and yours, this is just my stupid mistake from reading data, i dont have any data that relate in second table so it was empty.

---

I have a problem with joining tables to get some result from multiple tables. I have multiple tables without relationship like this:

Order:

```
Id . Name 
---------
1  . abc
2  . def
```

OrderDetail

```
Id . OrderId . Value
---------------------
1  .    1    .   35
2  .    1    .   24 
3  .    2    .   45
```

I want to get some result from `OrderDetail`, but the condition must be in `Order`, like this:

```
SELECT od.* 
FROM Order o, OrderDetail od 
WHERE o.id = od.OrderId AND o.name = 'abc';
```

I expect the result is will be like

```
OrderDetail

Id . OrderId . Value
1  .    1    .   35
2  .    1    .   24
```

but I got nothing from result, but if I run;

```
SELECT od.* 
FROM Order o, OrderDetail od 
WHERE o.id = od.OrderId;
```

I still get the whole result, my 2 tables don't have any relationship to each other.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]--that we can cut & paste & run. PS One does not need to know FKs or any other constraints to query. PS "i need the result in second table with the condition from first table" (from your comment) is not clear. Use enough words & sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The ANSI SQL standard still includes comma separated implicit join - but don't use them!

Answer (score 0):

Forget the join.  What does this return?

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.name = 'abc';
```

My guess is that it returns nothing.  So what you see as "abc" is not really "abc".  The most likely problem is hidden characters.  Start with characters at the beginning and end:

```
where o.name like '%abc%';
```

This can help you figure out if that is the problem.  If this still returns nothing, then maybe there are issues *between* chararacters:

```
where o.name like '%a%b%c%';
```

If this still returns nothing, then "a", "b" or "c" might be a bad character.  This becomes harder to figure out, unless you look at the actual character being stored.

Comment: thank for answer but it not about the character, i still get order item that i need from your first query, but when i need the result in second table with the condition from first table.

Answer (score 0):

Im so sorry guys, there is nothing wrong in my query and yours, this is just my stupid mistake from reading data, i dont have any data that relate in second table so it was empty. Thank for your time

Comment: Please consider deleting the question. You can still do that while it has no upvoted answers. The question is likely to be downvoted. It should be closed & deleted anyway according to [ask] since it was the result of a simple misundertanding re input values. (This is one of the reasons a [mcve] is required.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are after:

```
SELECT od.* FROM Order o
JOIN OrderDetail od ON o.id = od.OrderId 
WHERE o.name = 'abc';
```

Comment: That specifies the same result as the 1st query in the question. See the "answer" posted by the asker.